# What is syntax expression?

Tags: lisp, s-expression, land-of-lisp

I read in the book "Land of Lisp", the author mentions `syntax expression`. Does that mean the ability to express syntax as a form of data? Is this the same as `S-expression` (symbolic expression)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *symbolic expression* is data which is serialized as known from Lisp. It uses symbols, strings, numbers, lists and more. Lists are written in the form of `(` `expression`* `)`.

Thee author of *Land of Lisp* talks about *syntax expressions* and *Lisp syntax expressions*. Seems like this is something he invented (discovered?). ;-) He probably means an expression in Lisp syntax, where something like `(walk right)` is such an expression with the first element of the list being a verb.

In Common Lisp a valid expression of the programming language is called a [Lisp form](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/26_glo_f.htm#form). So an s-expression can express all kinds of data, but not all s-expressions are valid Lisp programs. For example `(defun)` is not a valid Common Lisp program, since it lacks a function name and a parameter list - plus the optional declarations, documentation and implementation body: `(defun foo ())`.

Comment: Alright, wonder why search results bring nothing about syntax expression, that's probably the reason. However, I still enjoy reading his book, since the reason I learn Lisp is because of the comic on Land of Lisp website :)